# Multi robot simulation in ROS

Tags: ros, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I have a problem with multi-robot simulation.

I have a launch file that launches two xacro files

```
 <param name="quad_urdf"
    command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py
    '$(find package)/models/quadrotorWithCamera.xacro'"
 />

<node name="spawn_quad0" 
  pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model"
  args="-urdf -param quad_urdf -model quad0 -x 0 -y 0 -z 3"
  respawn="false" output="screen">
</node>

<node name="spawn_quad1" 
  pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model"
  args="-urdf -param quad_urdf -model quad1 -x 1 -y 1 -z 3"
  respawn="false" output="screen">
</node>
```

The file quadrotorWithCamera.xacro loads a camera that publishes on /ptz/camera_info (as example of a topic).

Obviously, both quadrotors will publish on this topic and that's wrong. I see two solutions:

1. rename topic with remap. But it doesn't work. I set

   in both node but if I run rostopic list /ptz/camera_info is still on while /ptz/camera_info2 has no topic published on it.
2. Try to give as input to xacro file the robot name but it seems no input is available.

Any suggestion?

Thanks for any reply,

Neostek

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37582/multi-robot-simulation-in-ros/) by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2012-06-30

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-07-23**:
Can you share your simulation configuration files?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-01**:
What version of simulator gazebo are you running?  ROS topic remapping is broken in simulator_gazebo 1.6.10 and before (see http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/ChangeList/1.6), fixes are in 1.6.11, but the debian for that is being generated right now (http://www.ros.org/debbuild/fuerte.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try to put each node in a different namespace, using the ns attribute or the  tag so that you will hopefully get two different topics /ns1/ptz/camera_info and /ns2/ptz/camera_info.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Urcola](https://answers.ros.org/users/545/pablo-urcola/) with karma: 188 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I find a solution. The namespace has to be added as argument in the args field of the node, not as an attribute. In addition, I used namespace instead of ns:

---

Originally posted by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) with karma: 156 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you use namespaces for a node all parameters used by this node get the namespace as well. So when launch like the example in the above answer, the node *spawn_quad0* looks for a parameter *first_pelikan/quad_urdf* (and not just *quad_urdf*).

You can solve this in two ways:

```
<group ns="first_pelican">
   <param name="quad_urdf" value="....." />
   <node name="spawn_quad0" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param quad_urdf -model quad0 -x 0 -y 0 -z 3" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
</group>

<group ns="second_pelican">
   <param name="quad_urdf" value="....." />
   <node name="spawn_quad1" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param quad_urdf -model quad1 -x 1 -y 1 -z 3" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
</group>
```

Or, to avoid duplication of parameter, declare it outside the group, but use fully-qualified name when using the param (i.e with the slash at the beginning).

```
<param name="quad_urdf" value="....." />
 
<group ns="first_pelican">
  <node name="spawn_quad0" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param /quad_urdf -model quad0 -x 0 -y 0 -z 3" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
</group>

<group ns="second_pelican">
  <node name="spawn_quad1" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param /quad_urdf -model quad1 -x 1 -y 1 -z 3" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
</group>
```

The same is valid if you declare namespaces without the group, like:

```
<node name="foo" ns="first_pelican">
  <!-- becomes /first_pelican/param1 -->
  <param name="param1" value="0" />
</node>

<!-- all params in the included files gets the prefix of /first_pelican -->
<include file="file_to_include" ns="first_pelican" />
```

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4